# Adjusting subplots to make space for colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot some data and found constrained layout very helpful in maintaining margins and spaces between subplots. However, when I add a colorbar it reduces the width of all subplots and creates extra white space in the subplots above. This bcomes a problem when such plots are put up in reports where a lot of space goes waste because of extra space taken by colorbar.
I was wondering how I can avoid this and make only the image plots to resize when the colorbar is added without afecting the subplots above and no extra white space is created. An example code of the problem I am facing is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,2, constrained_layout=True)
ax[0,0].plot(range(10))
ax[0,1].plot(range(10))
ax[1,0].plot(range(10))
ax[1,1].plot(range(10))
ax[2,0].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
ax[2,1].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
ax[3,0].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
im = ax[3,1].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
bar = fig.colorbar(im,ax=[[ax[2,0],ax[2,1]],[ax[3,0],ax[3,1]]])
```

It'll be better if I can get this done with contrantrained_layout=True.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with adjusting the color bar, but what about the idea of adding a new axis and placing the color bar in the center? I set the placement values manually. I wanted to put the color bar in the bottom two graphs to make the widths the same, but I couldn't do that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,2, constrained_layout=True)
ax[0,0].plot(range(10))
ax[0,1].plot(range(10))
ax[1,0].plot(range(10))
ax[1,1].plot(range(10))
ax[2,0].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
ax[2,1].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
ax[3,0].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))
im = ax[3,1].pcolor(np.random.rand(2,2))

cax = fig.add_axes([0.48, 0.11, 0.05, 0.36])
bar = fig.colorbar(im,cax=cax,ax=[[ax[2,0],ax[2,1]],[ax[3,0],ax[3,1]]])

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.7, hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It still leaves a lot of space between the colorline plots which is not what I need right now. However, I did try a similar approach with 2 GridSpecs where I used a different gridspec for the image plots with a thin column on the right to place the subplot in. But this failed as the two grids stared to overlap.